# How to call external API in IBM watson chatbot and show the response in dialog box of chatbot

Tags: cloud, ibm-watson

I am trying to develop a chatbot using IBM Watson Conversation.  I developed the basic chatbot which will ask user details like username, fathername etc. Now i want to call an external service deployed in IBM cloud passing the user details and get the response in the chatbot box.

Right now i am calling the whole external API as a link tag and getting the response. But that response is in new tab of the web browser. I want to return the JSON response in chatbot.

Click **Link for user details**.
This tag of link for user details has
Click Link for user details.

Can anyone help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is described here:
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-actions.html#dialog-actions

In the JSON editor you can specify the service (IBM Cloud Function) and parameters like this

```
"context": {
    "variable_name" : "variable_value"
  },
  "actions": [
    {
      "name":"<actionName>",
      type":"client | server",
      "parameters": {
        "<parameter_name>":"<parameter_value>",
        "<parameter_name>":"<parameter_value>"
      },
      "result_variable": "<result_variable_name>",
      "credentials": "<reference_to_credentials>"
    }
  ],
  "output": {
    "text": "response text"
  }
```

If you specify for the type: server. You can provide the endpoint for you IBM Cloud Function. In this environment you can perform any action you like (including calling other services). Be aware of time outs though !

Another solution is to use the client option. Depending on you client, you should be able to call the service with the supplied parameters, but you have to do this all by yourself.